# Custom filter to Datatable

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, css-tables

I am trying to add my own filter to Data table's second column. Here below is my code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
table{
border:1px solid blue;
}
tr{
border:1px solid blue;
}
td{
border:1px solid blue;
}
tfoot input {
        width: 100%;
        padding: 3px;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }
</style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.12/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css">
<script>
// http://obvcode.blogspot.com/2007/11/easiest-way-to-check-ie-version-with.html
$(document).ready(function(){
    var table =  $('#mine').DataTable();

$('#mine tfoot th').each( function () {
        var title = $(this).text();
        $(this).html( '<input type="text" placeholder="Search '+title+'" />' );
    } );

$('#myInput').keyup( function() {
        table.draw();
    } );
});
</script>
<script>

function myFunction() {
  // Declare variables
  var input, filter, table, tr, td, i;
  input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  filter = input.value.toUpperCase();
  table = document.getElementById("mine");
  tr = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

  // Loop through all table rows, and hide those who don't match the search query
  for (i = 0; i < tr.length; i++) {
    td = tr[i].getElementsByTagName("td")[1];
    if (td) {
      if (td.innerHTML.toUpperCase().indexOf(filter) > -1) {
        tr[i].style.display = "";
      } else {
         tr[i].style.display = "none";
      }
      }
    }
  }

</script>
</head>
<body>
<table border="0" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5">
<tbody><tr>
<td>ade:</td><td>
<input type="text" id="myInput" name="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search for names.." title="Type in a name">
</td></tr>
</tbody></table>
    <table id="mine" class="display" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
<thead>
<th>a</th>
<th>a</th>
<th>a</th>
<th>a</th>
<th>a</th>
<th>a</th>
</thead>
 <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>a</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Start date</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
<tbody>
<tr><td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>q</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>q</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>q</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>saf</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>saf</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>saf</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
<tr><td>a</td>
<td>a</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td>
<td>b</td>
<td>c</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

The filter is working fine in the first page. But when the filter applied for entire table, if item present in first page of the table, it filters particular table row. But if the item present in the next page of the table , the filter will not be applied. can any one help me to solve this?

Comment: In `myFunction` can you log `tr.length` ? It usually has to do with when you fetch all table rows in `table.getElementsByTagName("tr")` it doesn't fetch all the table rows since `datatable.css` hides the rest of the table rows

Comment: @Arvind yes. what you said is right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because the rest of the table isn't available to the dom, you need to filter this with the datatables API. Kind of confusing, but datatables usually loads each page as it's called, to save on overhead. You can't search the entire datatable with just jquery (unless the entire table is displayed on your page), you'll need to use the API

However, datatables has a super cool regex filter search you can apply

Here's a snippet from a piece of code that may help. Although we may be using different versions (dataTable vs DataTable)

```
var search_text = [search text]
var table = $('[table selector]').dataTable().api();
       if (search_text){
         table
            .columns(3)
            .search('[REGEX SEARCH TEXT]', true, false)
            .draw();
       } 
    else{ 
        table
            .columns()
            .search('')
            .draw(); 

       }
     });
```

Here is a link to the datatables search API:

https://datatables.net/examples/api/regex.html